# In which scenario should I use both "width" in % and max-width value?

Tags: css

Reference [Are you using the right CSS units?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5wpD9Ov_To&t=124s)

I didn't fully understand when to use both `width` ( in % ) and `max-width` ?

Why should we use `%` for `width` ?

Comment: Are you just looking for a single scenario in which this might be useful, as an example to help understanding of the potential, or are you looking for a wide ranging answer? Trying to give a totally general answer would I think be either impossible, there are so many potential scenarios, or lead to opinion based answers which SO doesn’t allow.

Comment: Does that video's author show an example? If so please add it to your question, and be more specific in your question.

Comment: I'm trying to understand single scenario where this combination should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers are pretty straight forward, if you need something at a fixed size use pixels, if you need something to be dynamic like a navbar, use %. let's say you want the navbar content width to be 80% of the body width. it will now keep the same proportions on any screen size.

in other words, use % to make the size of an element **based on its parent**, and pixels to make something one fixed size

if this doesn't make sense I recommend looking at a tutorial or experimenting on your own with it